# Valgrind: Conditional jump depends on uninitialised value(s) created by a stack allocation

Tags: c, debugging, valgrind

When debugin my code, I'm getting a series of strange errors in Valgrind. The errors are all of the same type: "Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s) at ... Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation at ...".

Example of valgrind output:

```
==153367== Thread 6:
==153367== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==153367==    at 0x14B393: serializeNewAnnounce (topology_discovery.c:1146)
==153367==    by 0x1494A2: upon_AnnounceTimer (topology_discovery.c:360)
==153367==    by 0x148D87: topology_discovery_main_loop (topology_discovery.c:189)
==153367==    by 0x49EB608: start_thread (pthread_create.c:477)
==153367==    by 0x4B27102: clone (clone.S:95)
==153367==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation
==153367==    at 0x14AB00: serializeNewAnnounce (topology_discovery.c:1076)
==153367== 
==153367== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==153367==    at 0x14B3CC: serializeNewAnnounce (topology_discovery.c:1204)
==153367==    by 0x1494A2: upon_AnnounceTimer (topology_discovery.c:360)
==153367==    by 0x148D87: topology_discovery_main_loop (topology_discovery.c:189)
==153367==    by 0x49EB608: start_thread (pthread_create.c:477)
==153367==    by 0x4B27102: clone (clone.S:95)
==153367==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation
==153367==    at 0x14AB00: serializeNewAnnounce (topology_discovery.c:1076)
```

At a frist glance, this error seems to indicate that I forgot to initialize some memory.
However, up verifying several times, I can't find where exactly is the source of these errors.
The code is huge and with several functions, so I filtered only the important parts:

```
...
148 topology_discovery_state* state = malloc(sizeof(topology_discovery_state));
149 memset(state, 0, sizeof(topology_discovery_state));
...
260 state->neighbors = double_list_init(); // neighbors is a malloc and initializes head as NULL
...
... // The following code is within a single function, the previous is on another function
...
1047 unsigned int horizon = state->proto_args.horizon;
...
1050 unsigned char ptrs[horizon+1];
1051 memset(ptrs, 0, sizeof(ptrs));
...
1076 for(double_list_item* current_item = state->neighbors->head; current_item; current_item = current_item->next) {
1077 neighbor* current_neigh = (neighbor*) current_item->data;
...
1106 for(int h = 0; h <= horizon; h++) {
1107     ptrs[h] = levels[h]->size + ptrs[h-1];
1108 }
...
1145 int processed = 0;
1146 for(int h = 0; h <= horizon; h++) {
1147        int level_size = ptrs[h];
1148        int level_start = h == 0 ? 0 : ptrs[h-1];
1149        for(int node = level_start; node < level_size; node++) {
...
```

Only `state` is not a local variable and is passed as a parameter, the rest is all local to the same function.

Comment: At 1107, `ptrs[h-1]` is out of range index when `h == 0` (first iteration).

Comment: Thanks. But is that wat is generating this error? Wouldn't it generate index outof bounds of something like that instead?

Comment: I don't know but it might be indicative of similar errors.

Comment: `horizon` is probably not initialised

Comment: qrdl ```horizon``` is initialized (I updated the code to incude that line as well)

Comment: Weather Vane it was what you pointed out. How do I close the question?

Comment: @AndréRosa: When your question is resolved by a comment, you can either invite the commenter to post an answer, or post your own that explains what the problem was and how you fixed it.  In either case you can then click the check mark button to accept the answer, and then everyone will be able to see that it was resolved and what the answer was.  Closing is only used on SO for questions that cannot be answered at all (due to lack of details, etc) or that are off topic.

Answer (score 1):

At line 1107, in the first iteration, `ptrs` get index -1. Since in C array is actually a memory location and index interprete as pointer arithmetic, the result is access to the memory location that is one byte before `ptrs`, which is of course not initialized.